# Openshift's Cron doesn't work

Tags: php, cron, openshift

I have the following script named `chronograph.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f coins.php > chrono.dat
```

permission in `jobs.allow`:

```
#  Script or job files listed in here (one entry per line) will be
#  executed on a weekly-basis.
#
#  Example: The chronograph script will be executed weekly but the README 
#           and chrono.dat files in this directory will be ignored.
#
#           The README file is actually ignored due to the entry in the
#           jobs.deny which is checked before jobs.allow (this file).
#
chronograph.sh
```

and the cron's services started with this command: **ctl_app** start cron and this result:

```
CLIENT_RESULT: cron scheduling service is already enabled...
```

However, the script is never executed. If I run the script directly on the command line this works perfectly but can not get it to run automatic way. Some permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift and it should point you in the right direction.